# How to set package to create one unmarshaller for multiple classes?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have a spring boot application where I have used below dependency to unmarshal xml to java classes.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I have two Java classes which need to be unmarshalled.

First Java class is

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement(name = "appAsset")
@XmlAccessorType(FIELD)
public class EmployeeEvent {

    @XmlElement(name = "header")
    private Header header;

    @XmlElement(name = "employeeData")
    private Employee employee;
}
```

Second Java class is

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement(name = "appAsset")
@XmlAccessorType(FIELD)
public class CustomerEvent {

    @XmlElement(name = "header")
    private Header header;

    @XmlElement(name = "customerData")
    private Customer customer;
}
```

Unmarshaller class looks as below:

```
@Configuration
public class XmlConfig {

    @Bean
    public Unmarshaller unmarshaller() throws JAXBException {
        var jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.example.dto");
        var unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setAdapter(new OffsetDateTimeAdapter());

        return unmarshaller;
    }
}
```

Above unmarshaller bean is being used as below:

```
@Component
@Validated
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EmployeeConverter {

    private final Unmarshaller unmarshaller;

    public @Valid EmployeeEvent toEmployeeEvent(String xml) throws JAXBException,
            XMLStreamException {
        var xmlStreamReader =
                XMLInputFactory.newFactory().createXMLStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
        var xmlReaderWithoutNamespace = new XMLReaderWithoutNamespace(xmlStreamReader);

        return (EmployeeEvent) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlReaderWithoutNamespace);
    }
}
```

However, above configuration is giving error as below:

```
Error creating bean with name 'employeeConverter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'unmarshaller' defined in com.example.config.XmlConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller]: Factory method 'unmarshaller' threw exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: \"com.example.dto\" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index"}
```

after this error, I added jaxb.index file in package com.example.dto as below.

```
EmployeeEvent
CustomerEvent
```

However, still error is same as it's unable to locate jaxb.index file.

**How to resolve this issue? Does spring boot need any extra configuration?**

I tried another approach , after reading multiple stackoverflow posts, to provide list of classes and then you don't need to add jaxb.index or ObjectFactory.class as below. Still, i did not get any luck as below configuration gave ClassCastException.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.example.dto.CustomerEvent cannot be cast to class com.example.dto.EmployeeEvent (com.example.dto.EmployeeEvent and com.example.dto.CustomerEvent are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Now, Unmarshaller class looks as below:

```
@Configuration
public class XmlConfig {

    @Bean
    public Unmarshaller unmarshaller() throws JAXBException {
        var jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(EmployeeEvent.class , CustomerEvent.class);
        var unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setAdapter(new OffsetDateTimeAdapter());

        return unmarshaller;
    }
}
```

**I feel I am missing some configuration with respect to spring boot. Any pointer to resolve this ?**

Comment: Could you show us this `ClassCastException` with exception message?

Comment: @MichałZiober Exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.example.dto.CustomerEvent cannot be cast to class com.example.dto.EmployeeEvent (com.example.dto.EmployeeEvent and com.example.dto.CustomerEvent are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Comment: It looks like there is a good reason to throw `ClassCastException`. If you passed `XML` payload like this `<CustomerEvent>....</CustomerEvent>` to method `toEmployeeEvent` you can not expect `EmployeeEvent` at the output. Unmarshalling works properly and you need to check result before casting.

Comment: @MichałZiober  var jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(EmployeeEvent.class , CustomerEvent.class); says that it gives single context which can be utilized for all the mentioned classes. Hence, how can I get single context for multiple classes

Comment: `JAXBContext.newInstance(EmployeeEvent.class , CustomerEvent.class)` means you created single context for these classes and all other classes `JAXB` can find based on these two classes. So, you can provide at least two different `XML` payloads: `<CustomerEvent>....</CustomerEvent>` and `<EmployeeEvent>....</EmployeeEvent>` and unmarshaller will decide which type to create using payload you provided. So, before casting you need to be sure the returned value from unmarshalling process is what you expected.

Comment: @MichałZiober If I am providing CustomerEvent, it should unmarshal that into CustomerEvent class but it's not behaving in that way. It's unable to unmarshal in correct event type. If I am providing customer event xml , it's trying to map to employee event class

Comment: Could you please create a simple example which I could run and test?